# un-https specific urls with mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an apache vhost listening on port :443

I am trying to redirect any https requests back to http unless they meet the condition of being

1. from the domain `www.site.co.uk`
2. and contain *either* `/alpha` or `/beta` in the uri part of the request

I have the following statements in the config along with commented logic I though the process follows, but `https://www.mysite.co.uk/alpha` and `https://www.mysite.co.uk/beta` are being 301'd somehow

have I misunderstood the logic flow for conditional rewrites ?

```
RewriteEngine On

# if host submitted is not 'www.mysite.co.uk' un-https the url (i.e. catchall)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,L,R=301]

# otherwise IF THE domain is 'www.mysite.co.uk
# *and* if the uri does not contain 'alpha' *or* 'beta' un-https the url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/alpha/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/beta/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,L,R=301]

# otherwise the domain must be www.mysite.co.uk
# and the uri must contain '/alpha' *or* '/beta'
# in which case do nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules that you have is a logical **OR** of URI not contains `/alpha` or `/beta`. You need all the conditions to be *and*'ed together. Just remove the `[OR]` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/alpha/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/beta/? [NC]
```

It's a logical negation expansion. Say *A* is `/alpha` and *B* is `/beta`. !A is thus not `/alpha`. So when you say !(A or B), if you expand the `!`, you get !A **and** !B.